# Is there a good way to compile .pyx cython files for AWS Lmabda?

Tags: python, cython

So I'm currently compiling `.pyx` files using a AWS EC2 instance because I didn't find a way to do it locally on my macbook. Is there an obvious solution to do this locally or do I just continue with how I'm doing it?

I thought maybe setting the `platform` kwarg to `'manylinux2014_x86_64'` in my `setup.py` might work but no luck.

code:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize  # pip

script = 'some.pyx'

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(script),
    # platforms='manylinux2014_x86_64'
)
```

calling `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` from the terminal

p.s. I have spent a significant amount of time researching this, sadly. Sometimes the answer is just I'm a bad "Googler"

Comment: Are you compiling for a different architecture than you're currently using?

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for asking I didn't think of that. It does happen to be that my computer is `x86_64`(running `uname -m`) and the lambda function displays `x86_64`. My processor is intel though